# Which way is correct when I integrate GitHub to my Android Studio 3.3.1 project?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I hope to use GitHub in my Android Studio 3.3.1 project. I google some ways, I find the ways divide into two way.

**Way 1:** Such as   https://medium.com/code-yoga/how-to-link-android-studio-with-github-312037a13b99

```
   It need  VCS > Import into Version Control > Share project on Github
```

**Way2 :** Such as  https://www.londonappdeveloper.com/how-to-use-git-hub-with-android-studio/

```
   It need VCS > Import into Version Control > Create Git Repository.
```

What are different between Way 1 and Way2 ?

What are different between *Share project on Github* and *Create Git Repository and Other operations* ?

Way 1 is very simple, but I don't know if it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

In the 2nd link you posted : the author guides you through the following steps

1. create an empty git repo on github throught github's web GUI
2. create a project and an empty repo on your local machine
3. link your local repo with the remote repo on github (through a cli command : `git remote add ...`)

In the 1st link you posted :

steps 1. and 3. are managed through the IDE, when the author describes the step "3. Share on Github"

---

a note about the "private" flag : when following the walkthrough of the 2nd article, you can select "Private" in github's GUI when you create the empty repository on github.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that the two way do same work, and Way 1 is better simple?

Answer (score 0):

1st way - you're going to share your current git repository/project to online with Github.

2nd way - The first phase to make a project to turn into a git repository. You must make this thing first before uploading in Github.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't know the operation of 1st way is  share  current git repository/project to online with Github.

Comment: I can set Private for my project when I use 1st way

Answer (score 0):

1st way: y are sharing your code to you git repository if you already have one else you will create a new repo and then add files
This command creates an empty Git repository—basically a .git directory with subdirectories for objects, refs/heads, refs/tags, and template files. An initial HEAD file that references the HEAD of the master branch is also created.

2nd way: in second way you are making your localfiles as your local reppository which you can puch and merge in you online git account

you certainly would want to take a look at this awesome and simpolified tutorial of whole git process. Hope it Helps 
happy Coding;
exit();

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

You have git enabled local project not in github, so you have to upload to github. thats why it says

> VCS > Import into Version Control > Share project on Github

**Way 2**

Initially, you create a new empty git repository on github, after that you created android project (not a git project) then push your code to git repository

***I always use 1st way***

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that the two ways can get the same result, and Way 1 is better simple?